# How to preview the correct image which select from canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rect = {};
var drag = false;
var storeRects = [];
var isMoving = false;
make_base();
init();


function make_base() {
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg';
  base_image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 800, 500); 
  }
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function init() {

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    drag = true;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    if(drag) {
        isMoving = true;
        rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY ;
        draw();
    }
}

function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0 ,0, 800, 500);
    storeRects.forEach(function(rect) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(rect.x, rect.y,rect.w, rect.h);
        context.stroke();
    });


    context.lineWidth="1";
    context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    context.stroke();
}

function mouseUp() {
    drag = false;
    if(isMoving === true) {
        storeRects.push({
            x: rect.startX,
            y: rect.startY,
            w: rect.w,
            h: rect.h,
        });

        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvasPreview");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var pre_base_image = new Image();
        pre_base_image.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg';
        ctx.drawImage(pre_base_image,
(Math.min(storeRects[0].x, storeRects[0].x + Math.abs(storeRects[0].w)) / canvas.width) * pre_base_image.width,
(Math.min(storeRects[0].y, storeRects[0].y + Math.abs(storeRects[0].h)) / canvas.height) * pre_base_image.height,
(Math.abs(storeRects[0].w) / canvas.width) * pre_base_image.width , 
(Math.abs(storeRects[0].h) / canvas.height) * pre_base_image.height,
0, 0, 
Math.abs(storeRects[0].w), 
Math.abs(storeRects[0].h)
);
        isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="myCanvasPreview" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    </canvas>
```

When I select the person in the image, I would like to preview it on another canvas.
Now, I can preview but seems like the area is not correct.

[image]

Comment: Your calculation of point X and Y seems to be wrong

Comment: Another thing I noticed: you load an image of 600x400, render it to a 800x600 canvas, then try to map the selection coordinates for that canvas on a 600x400 image that you load to draw on the second canvas. That will of course be off. Worked locally when I rescalled everything to the right dimensions. Blindman67's reaction solved the issue much better though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have the correct coordinates. You must specify the top left corner (the min coordinates)

Also you need to scale to the image size.

This will fix the existing code.

```
ctx.drawImage(pre_base_image,
    (Math.min(storeRects[0].x, storeRects[0].x + Math.abs(storeRects[0].w)) / canvas.width) * pre_base_image.width,
    (Math.min(storeRects[0].y, storeRects[0].y + Math.abs(storeRects[0].h)) / canvas.height) * pre_base_image.height,
    (Math.abs(storeRects[0].w) / canvas.width) * pre_base_image.width , 
    (Math.abs(storeRects[0].h) / canvas.height) * pre_base_image.height,
    0, 0, 
    Math.abs(storeRects[0].w), 
    Math.abs(storeRects[0].h)
);
```

Check your previous question as I added an answer that takes care of this problem befor you need to do the above code.

Comment: You were a bit faster than me. This fix is not ideal yet though: if you drag from a certain point to left-up, you will see it is still off.

Comment: @Zomry yep found that just as you added the comment.